# Can I specify an Application or Context-Specific tag with C# BerConverter.Encode()?

Tags: c#, encoding, asn.1, ber

.NET's System.DirectoryServices.Protocols assembly specifies a light-weight ASN.1 BER encoder, but the documentation is not great: [`BerConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.berconverter.encode(v=vs.110).aspx).

You call it by specifying a format string and a list of objects to encode.

- `INTEGER`s can be encoded with format characters `i` or `e`
- `OCTET STRING`s can be encoded with `o` character
- `SEQUENCE`s can be encoded with `{` and `}`
- etc.

I'd really like to make use of this simple converter so I don't have to take on an additional dependency. Taking on a dependency is undesirable because C# is callable from Powershell, and it is great to distribute a script that does something fancy with C# so long as it doesn't require an assembly that isn't included with .NET.

However, BerConverter doesn't seem to have a way to specify an Application or Context-Specific tag, which are often used to remove ambiguity in ASN.1, for example when components of a constructed type are marked as `OPTIONAL`

So, I can encode the following:

`BerConverter.Encode("{i{i}}", 1, 2);`

Which gives:

`30 84 00 00 00 0c 02 01 01 30 84 00 00 00 03 02 01 02`

But, if that second sequence needs to be `[Application 1]` or `61`... I'm not sure what to put in the format string to emit that in the encoding.

Does BerConverter even have this capability?

Comment: You could try to use a decompiler (e.g. ILSpy) and look in the BerConverter code to see what it does.

Comment: @bosonix Thanks for the comment. I don't know why I didn't think to decompile. I used JetBrains dotPeek to decompile `BerConverter.Encode()`, and I found out that it is calling `ber_printf()` under the covers. It has better documentation. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why I didn't just do this up front, but I used a decompiler to look at the code.  I found that `BerConverter.Encode()` is based on [`ber_printf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366089(v=vs.85).aspx), which has much better documentation.

From the docs:

> **Character:** 't'
>
> **Description:**
>
> **Tag**. The next argument is a *ber_tag_t* that specifies the tag to override the next element written to the *BerElement*. This works across calls.

So, I was able to change my code to:

`BerConverter.Encode("{it{i}}", 1, 0x61, 2)`

Which allows me to set the tag value to `0x61` and the code emits:

`30 84 00 00 00 0c 02 01 01 61 84 00 00 00 03 02 01 02`